# find all by name query consult

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to return all the name that exist in a Category model.
but only the name to put in array,
I am using rails 3.2 and rubu 2.0. I try this

```
Category.find_all_by_name()
```

but don´t work! It is possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Category.select("DISTINCT name").pluck(:name)
```

**Please** do not use a select with `.all` and map(&:id) as it is way slower and hogs more memory because all results are loaded and instantiated as objects.

Answer (score 3):

Use [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) if you are in `Rails 3.2` or greater.

```
Category.pluck(:name)
```

It will return an `Array` with all the names

Comment: `pluck` is available only on `Rails >= 3.2`

Comment: @act_as_greek yes it has mentioned that it is using rails 3.2 so it will work in your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all the names present in category model, then try this code:

```
Category.all.map(&:name)
```